# Is the following a conic section

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

All vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and only $\mathbf{r} = \left[ x; y; z \right]$ is unknown. My question is does the following system define a conic section in the $x-y$ plane and, if so, how can I find it:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}^\mathrm{T} \left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right]
 & = 0 \\
\\
\mathbf{v}_1^\mathrm{T} \frac {\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_1} {\Vert \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_1 \Vert } + \mathbf{v}_2^\mathrm{T} \frac {\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_2} {\Vert \mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_2 \Vert } & = c
\end{align}
$$

If either $\Vert \mathbf{v}_1 \Vert = 0$ or $\Vert \mathbf{v}_2 \Vert = 0$, then the above is the intersection of a cone and the $z=0$ plane. Likewise if $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}_1$ or $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}_2$. However, I have been unable to figure out what the above represents in the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these are not conic sections in general.

Your first equation forces $z = 0$.  For \begin{align*}
\mathbf{r}_1 = \mathbf{v}_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\ 
\mathbf{r}_2 = \mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
with $c = 0$, your second equation reduces to 
$$  \frac{x}{\sqrt{|x|^2+|y-1|^2}} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{|x-1|^2+|y|^2}} = 0  \text{.}  $$

This is not the equation of a conic section.  It is the line $y = 1-x$ for $x \in (-\infty, 0] \cup [1,\infty)$ joined by the arc of the circle centered at $(1/2,1/2)$ with radius $1/2$ for the angles in the interval $[3\pi/4, 7\pi/4]$.

[image: c=0]

Changing only $c=3/2$, it's not a conic section.

[image: c=3/2]

Changing $\mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and setting $c = 1/2$, the graph loses its symmetry.

[image: Double v2 and c=1/2]

The $r_i$ seems to control where the pieces of the piecewise curve meet.  Many choices of $c$ give no solutions (which is another thing that cannot happen with a planar section of [nappes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Nappe.html)).

Why would you believe there is a short description of what is represented by varying the parameters in your equation?

Comment: There is another constraint that I failed to include because I thought it made the question simpler, viz. $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the foci of a certain ellipsoid on which $r$ must lie. I originally asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323060/how-to-solve-this-non-linear-system-ellipsoid-plane-cone-intersection) question several years ago but got no response. I thought starting with this question would increase my chances and maybe point me in the right direction. I *thought* there was an equivalent single-cone representation of the problem but I could very well be wrong.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 : Well, none of these is a conic section, so intersection with a third constraint is not going to produce a conic section...

Answer (score 1):

If $r_1=r_2$ then it is clear that it is a comic section because

$(v_1^T+v_2^T)(r-r_1)=c||r-r_1||$

so

$c^2||r-r_1||^2-((v_1^T+v_2^T)(r-r_1))^2=0$

that is an equation of a polynomial of order $2$

In general you have

$||r-r_2||v_1^T(r-r_1)+||r-r_1||v_2^T(r-r_2)=c||r-r_1||||r-r_2||$

so

$(||r-r_2||v_1^T(r-r_1)+||r-r_1||v_2^T(r-r_2))^2-(c||r-r_1||||r-r_2||)^2=0$

The problems are the factors

$(||r-r_2||v_1^T(r-r_1))^2$

$(||r-r_1||v_2^T(r-r_2))^2$

and $(||r-r_2||v_1^T(r-r_1)) (||r-r_2||v_1^T(r-r_1))$

The first two factors are polynomials of order $3$ while in the last factor there is a root square.

Comment: So the answer is that it is not a conic section due to the cubic and square root terms. Do you know what, if anything, it does represent?

Comment: When this terms are Zero then you have a conic section

Answer (score 1):

Assume the space Eucledean space $E^3\equiv\textbf{R}^3$ and 
$$
\overline{r}=\overline{r}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\{f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3),f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3),f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)\}\tag 1
$$
is any vector. The   $\overline{\nu}_1,\overline{\nu}_2,\overline{r}_1,\overline{r}_2$  are constant vectors in $E^3$.

Set also   $\overline{\nu}_1=\overline{A}=\textrm{const}$ and $\overline{\nu}_2=\overline{B}=\textrm{const}$. Also $\overline{r}_1=\textrm{const}$ and $\overline{r}_2=\textrm{const}$ and $\overline{\Gamma}=\overline{r}_1-\overline{r}_2=\textrm{const}$. Then if we set $\overline{w}_1$ and $\overline{w}_2$ to be such that
$$
\overline{w}_1=\overline{r}-\overline{r}_1\tag 2
$$
and
$$
\overline{w}_2=\overline{r}-\overline{r}_2.\tag 3
$$
Also
$$
R_1=\frac{1}{|\overline{w}_1|}\textrm{ and }R_2=\frac{1}{|\overline{w}_2|}.
$$
Using iner products, your relation becomes equivalently  $(\overline{w}_2=\overline{w}_1+\overline{\Gamma})$
$$
\left\langle\overline{\nu}_1,\frac{\overline{w}_1}{|\overline{w}_1|}\right\rangle+\left\langle\overline{\nu}_2,\frac{\overline{w}_2}{|\overline{w}_2|}\right\rangle=\textrm{const}.\tag 4
$$
Hence
$$
\left\langle \overline{\nu}_1,\overline{w}_1R_1\right\rangle+\left\langle \overline{\nu}_2,\overline{w}_2R_2\right\rangle=c\Leftrightarrow 
$$
$$
R_1\left\langle \overline{\nu}_1,\overline{w}_1\right\rangle+R_2\left\langle \overline{\nu}_2,\overline{w}_1\right\rangle+\left\langle\overline{\nu}_2,\overline{\Gamma}\right\rangle R_2=c\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\left\langle R_1\overline{\nu}_1+R_2\overline{\nu}_2,\overline{w}_1\right\rangle+\left\langle\overline{\nu}_2,\overline{\Gamma}\right\rangle R_2=c\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\left|R_1\overline{\nu}_1+R_2\overline{\nu}_2\right|\cos (\phi)\frac{1}{R_1}+k_1 R_2=c.
$$
Hence
$$
\sqrt{A^2R_1^2+2C_1R_1R_2+B^2R_2^2}\cdot\frac{\cos(\phi)}{R_1}+k_1R_2=c,\tag 5
$$
where $\phi$ is the angle between $R_1\overline{\nu}_1+R_2\overline{\nu}_2$ and $\overline{w}_1$. Also $A,B,C_1$ are constants.

But
$$
\frac{1}{R_1^2}-\frac{1}{R_2^2}=|\overline{w}_1+\overline{r}_1|^2-|\overline{w}_1|^2=\left\langle \overline{w}_1+\overline{\Gamma},\overline{w}_1+\overline{\Gamma}\right\rangle-|\overline{w}_1|^2=
$$
$$
=2\left\langle \overline{w}_1,\overline{\Gamma}\right\rangle+|\overline{\Gamma}|^2=\frac{2}{R_1}|\overline{\Gamma}|\cos \theta+|\overline{\Gamma}|^2.
$$
If we set $|\overline{\Gamma}|=k_2$, then
$$
\frac{1}{R_2^2}=\frac{1}{R_1^2}-\frac{2k_2\cos(\theta)}{R_1}-k_2^2,\tag 6
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\overline{w}_1=\overline{r}-\overline{r}_1$ and $\overline{\Gamma}$.

Solving (6) with respect to $R_2$, we get
$$
R_2=\frac{R_1}{\sqrt{1-k_2^2R_1^2-2k_2R_1\cos(\theta)}}
$$
Setting
$$
R_2=\frac{R_1}{R_3}
$$ 
we get
$$
R_3=\sqrt{1-k_2^2R_1^2-2k_2R_1\cos(\theta)}\tag 7
$$
Solving with respect to $R_1$, we get
$$
R_1=\frac{-2\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3-2R_3^2+\cos(2\theta)}}{2k_2}.\tag 8
$$
Hence also
$$
R_2=\frac{-2\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3-2R_3^2+\cos(2\theta)}}{2k_2R_3}.\tag 9
$$
Stting $(8),(9)$ to $(5)$, we get
$$
\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{-2 R_3^2+\cos(2 \theta)+3}-2\cos(\theta)\right)[-A^2 k_2^2 R_3^2 \cos ^2(\phi)-B^2k_2^2 \cos ^2(\phi)+c^2 k_2^2 R_3^2-
$$
$$
-\sqrt{2} c k_1 k_2 R_3 \sqrt{-2R_3^2+\cos (2 \theta)+3}+2 c k_1 k_2 R_3 \cos (\theta)-2 C_1k_2^2 R_3 \cos ^2(\phi)-
$$
$$
-\sqrt{2} k_1^2 \cos (\theta) \sqrt{-2 R_3^2+\cos (2 \theta)+3}-k_1^2 R_3^2+k_1^2 \cos (2 \theta)+2 k_1^2]=0.\tag{10}
$$
Hence one solution is
$$
R_3=\frac{\sqrt{3-2\cos^2(\theta)+\cos(2\theta)}}{\sqrt{2}}=1\textrm{, }R_1=0
$$
and for the other solutions we write from $(10)$
$$
-A^2 k_2^2 R_3^2 \cos ^2(\phi)-B^2k_2^2 \cos ^2(\phi)+c^2 k_2^2 R_3^2
+2 c k_1 k_2 R_3 \cos (\theta)-
$$
$$
-2 C_1k_2^2 R_3 \cos ^2(\phi)
-k_1^2 R_3^2+k_1^2 \cos (2 \theta)+2 k_1^2=
$$
$$
=\sqrt{2} c k_1 k_2 R_3 \sqrt{-2R_3^2+\cos (2 \theta)+3}+\sqrt{2} k_1^2 \cos (\theta) \sqrt{-2 R_3^2+\cos (2 \theta)+3}.\tag{11}
$$
Squaring equation $(11)$ and setting 
$$
X=k_2^2(B^2+R_3(2C_1+A^2R_3))\cos^2(\phi),\tag{12a}
$$ 
$$
Y=c^2k_2^2R_3^2+k_1^2(-1+R_3^2)+2ck_1k_2R_3\cos(\theta)\tag{12b}
$$
$$
Z=k_1^2(3-2R_3^2+\cos(2\theta)),\tag{12c}
$$
we get
$$
X^2+Y^2-2X(Y+Z)=0.\tag{13}
$$
Which is a surface in $E^3$. Hence
$$
X^2+Y^2-2X(Y+Z)=0\Leftrightarrow R_3=f_3(\phi,\theta)\Leftrightarrow R_1=f_1(\phi,\theta)\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$ 
|\overline{r}-\overline{r}_1|=\frac{1}{f_1(\phi,\theta)}
$$ 
If we set
$$
S:\overline{x}=\{X,Y,\frac{(X-Y)^2}{2X}\},
$$
with
$$
E=\left\langle\partial_X\overline{x},\partial_X\overline{x}\right\rangle
$$
$$
G=\left\langle\partial_Y\overline{x},\partial_Y\overline{x}\right\rangle,
$$
$$
F=\left\langle\partial_X\overline{x},\partial_Y\overline{x}\right\rangle.
$$
Then $Z=\frac{(X-Y)^2}{2X}$ defines a surface iff
$$
W^2=EG-F^2=\frac{9 X^4-8 X^3 Y+2 X^2 Y^2+Y^4}{4 X^4}\neq 0
$$
The Gauss curvature of $S$ (after evaluation) is $K=0$ and it is easy to see that $(k):X^2+Y^2-2XY-2YZ=0$ is a cone. The equation $Z=0$ defines a plane. Here $Z=0$ is $R_3^2=1+\cos^2(\theta)$ or equivalently $R_1=-\frac{1}{k_2}\cos(\theta)\Leftrightarrow |\overline{r}-\overline{r}_1|=-\frac{k_2}{\cos(\theta)}$ (is a plane) and $\theta$ is the angle of $\overline{r}$ and $\overline{\Gamma}$, where $\overline{\Gamma}$ is a constant vector. Hence $Z=0\Leftrightarrow |\overline{r}-\overline{r}_1|=-\frac{k_2}{\cos(\theta)}$ is a plane.

In the case $Y=0$ we have$...R_1=\textrm{const}$, which is a sphere. Hence in this case we have intersection of cone and sphere.

However the transformation $(12a,b,c),(13)$ is not linear and not easy to compute. The best way to give evaluations is to find function $f_1(\phi,\theta)$. This can be done as follows: Put $X,Y,Z$ into $(13)$ and solve with respect to $R_3$. Then set $R_3$ to $(8)$ and find $f_1(\phi,\theta)$.

Here is the polynomial equation of $R_3$ (it is a 4th degree):
$$
[(k_1^2+c^2k_2^2)^2+2A^2k_2^2(k_1^2-ck_2^2)\cos^2(\phi)+A^4k_2^4\cos^4(\phi)]R_3^4+
$$
$$
+4 k_2 [C_1k_2 \cos^2(\phi) \left(A^2 k_2^2 \cos ^2(\phi)-c^2 k_2^2+k_1^2\right)+
$$
$$
+c k_1 \cos (\theta) \left(-A^2 k_2^2 \cos^2(\phi)+c^2 k_2^2+k_1^2\right)]R_3^3-
$$
$$
-2 [k_2^2 (\cos^2(\phi) (-k_2^2 \cos^2(\phi) \left(A^2 B^2+2 C_1^2\right)+k_1^2 \left(2 A^2-B^2\right)+B^2 c^2k_2^2+
$$
$$
+4 cC_1 k_1 k_2 \cos (\theta))
+k_1^2 \cos (2 \theta) \left(A^2 \cos ^2(\phi)-c^2\right))+k_1^4]R_3^2-
$$
$$
-4 k_2 [k_1k_2 \cos^2(\phi) \left(B^2 c k_2 \cos (\theta)+C_1 k_1 (\cos (2 \theta)+2)\right)-B^2 C_1 k_2^3 \cos^4(\phi)+
$$
$$
+c k_1^3 \cos (\theta)]R_3
+B^4 k_2^4 \cos^4(\phi)-2 B^2 k_1^2 k_2^2 \cos^2(\phi)(\cos (2\theta)+2)+k_1^4=0
$$